# plotting interacting in jupyter facing errors

Tags: python, interactive, ipywidgets

Hi I am trying to have an interactive plot in jupyter notebook, but when I try adding this %matplotlib notebook to the beginning of my code, I get an error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: '/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/web_backend/js/mpl.js'
so I used the alternative way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytz
import math
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider
from IPython.display import clear_output    
def IntervalSlider(interval):
startDate = '2015-03-01'
endDate = str(pd.to_datetime(startDate) + pd.DateOffset(days=interval))
mask = countHourly[countHourly['datetime_combined'].between(startDate, endDate)]
x = mask['datetime_combined']
y = mask['count']
clear_output(wait=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))
plt.bar(x, y,width = 0.05)

interact(IntervalSlider, interval=FloatSlider(min=1, max=100, step=1, value=1))
```

and now I get new plots whenever I move the slider. Is there any solution for this or my first question?

Comment: Please always post a minimal reproducible example as a code block sharing your issue. See under 'Help others reproduce the problem' at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also please actually clear the kernel and try to run anything you post alone in a new notebook as a way to test if it is a minimal reproducible example. If you did that with the actual code here, you'd see that line after `def IntervalSlider(interval):` is a problem aside from what you are trying to post about. Help those that are here to help you by making it easy to run your code.